# Consequence of Modularity theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, galois-representations

In book of Fred Diamond a first course in modular form in *chapeter 9 theorem 9.6.3* it said that let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $Q$ then for some new from $f \in s_{2}(\gamma_{0}(N))$ with number field $Q$ 
Then $\rho_{E.p} \sim \rho_{f.p}$  for all $p$.
And there is also another theorem of modularity in chapter 8 theorem 8.8.3 
Let E be an elliptic curve over $Q$ with conductor N then for some newfrom f∈$s_{2}(\gamma_{0}(N))$ we have 
$L(E.s)=L(f.s)$
**Question :** is this two difintion are equivalente ? (if it is not .what is the diffrent between them)

$$\rho_{E.p} \sim \rho_{f.p} \iff L(E.s)=L(f.s)$$

Where $L(E.s)$ is the L_function of elliptic curve $E$ and $L(f.s)$ is the L-function of the newfrom $f$

Comment: It is not at all about solutions in $\Bbb{Q,Z,N}$ but about the Galois representation and L-series and number of points modulo $p$ of $E$'s reductions. That it is modular makes it much simpler with a lot of useful properties. For two elliptic curves (more generally abelian varieties) $L(E,s)\approx L(E_2,s)$ (up to finitely many L-factors) is equivalent to $E,E_2$ are isogeneous and for a $\Gamma_0(N)$ cusp eigenform $f$ of weight 2 then $L(f,s)$ is always the L-series of the abelian variety corresponding to the complex torus obtained by integrating $2i\pi f(z)dz$.

Comment: (for abelian varieties over number fields the L-series of [twists](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06894) must agree too). The weight 2 is because if $F$ is of weight $0$ then $F'$ is of weight $2$, when integrating $f(z)dz$ we obtain something almost of weight $2$, except that $\int_{i\infty}^{\gamma.i\infty}f(z)\ne 0$. When $f$ is an eigenform with rational coefficients the $\int_{i\infty}^{\gamma.i\infty}f(z)$ organize themselves to be contained in a common lattice $u\Bbb{Z}+v\Bbb{Z}$ and so $\Gamma_0(N).p \mapsto\int_{i\infty}^p f(z)dz$ is holomorphic $X_0(N) \to \Bbb{C}/(u\Bbb{Z}+v\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: I don't mean morphism between two elliptic curve i mean that is the L-function of E equale to the L-function of the newfrom f is that the same as morphism of galois representation

Comment: Two elliptic curves are isogeneous (over $\Bbb{Q}$) iff they have the same Galois representation iff they have the same L-series, it is not difficult to show. About the $\Bbb{Q}$ points of $E$ : That $f$ is modular implies we can compare its algebraic rank (computed from the algebraic methods explained in Silverman) with its analytic rank (order of vanishing at $s=1$) and check the BSD conjecture (which is true for elliptic curves over $\Bbb{Q}$ of analytic rank $\le 1$ as a consequence of the modularity theorem).

Comment: You said that it is not about solustion in $N$ $Z$ but wahy in fermat's last theorem .when wiles proov by contradiction that there is no modular form of frey curve that ⇒ that fermat have no solustion in integer

Comment: [Because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribet%27s_theorem) a rational point of odd $p$-th Fermat curve can be used to construct an elliptic curve whose equation and discriminant has weird properties to which Ribet level lowering shows its reduction is the reduction of a level 2 modular form which doesn't exist.

Comment: So if we have a similar curve called T like frey curve and we proov that L(E.s)=/=L(f.s) that mean that there is no modular form of this curve T  ⇒ T have no integer solustion. is that true ?

Comment: @reuns Two Galois representations being isomorphic iff they have the same $L$-series is easy to show. Two elliptic curves having the same Galois representation if and only if they are isogenous is Faltings' isogeny theorem, and is definitely not easy to show!!

Comment: Do you read the bookof fred in this case it is not morphism between two fifferent curve . This is another version of modularity theorem i said if they equale

Comment: @Abdallahchaibeddrra did you read the explanation underneath Theorem 9.6.3? It explains the equivalence between the Galois representation theoretic version of the modularity theorem and "Version $a_p$", which is equivalent to the $L$-functions version (Theorem 8.8.3).